# Are there examples on how I can use state compression for other than cNFTs

Tags: compression, cnft

I think it would be a great idea to try to use compression for something like whitelist? Trying to find examples for this.

Also, if I'm wrong how has whitelisting been done before? I'd like to avoid the use of Metaplex tools if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Another example I've seen using compression is Gum. They're an open source social layer, you can check out their docs and code here.

https://github.com/gumhq

Comment: is it me or is their site down?

Comment: adjusted the link to the projects github, has source code and docs. thanks for the flag!